# Django caching - Pickle is slow

Tags: python, django, caching, serialization, pickle

Working on optimization of one web-site, I found, that finally pickling of QuerySets becomes bottleneck in caching, and no matter how clever your code could be, unpickling of relatively large QS in time of 1-2secs will kill all effort.

Does anybody encountered this?

Answer (score 3):

If you are currently just using pickle, might I recommend [cPickle](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/lib/module-cPickle.html) which is purported to be up to 1000 times faster.

Comment: In that case, you might consider [Marshall](http://docs.python.org/2/library/marshal.html) as it is much faster, but, as the docs say, not secure against erroneous or malicious data.

Comment: @GillBates: If you use cPickle and still observe these 1-2 second unpicklings, it seems that those querysets must be quite huge. How big are they? Do you really need to cache all that data?

Comment: @Tadgh According to the docs on Marshall, atleast in python 3.8, that is not true. Taken directly from the docs `...use the pickle module instead – the performance is comparable...`

Answer (score 0):

[ultrajson](https://github.com/esnme/ultrajson) to the rescue!

```
In [1]: from string import letters

In [3]: import ujson

In [5]: import cPickle as pickle

In [7]: import random

In [8]: def random_string(n=10): return ''.join([random.choice(letters) for _ in xrange(n)])

In [9]: DATA = {random_string(): list(range(1000)) for _ in xrange(1000)}

In [12]: %timeit -r 3 -n 100 ujson.dumps(DATA)
100 loops, best of 3: 89.2

In [13]: %timeit -r 3 -n 100 pickle.dumps(DATA)
100 loops, best of 3: 285 ms per loop
```